# does not contain a definition for 'ddlPeriodStamp_SelectedIndexChanged' and no extension method 'ddlPeriodStamp_Selectedindexedchanged

Tags: c#, asp.net

Kindly help to fix this. I am getting this error.

> " does not contain a definition for
>   'ddlPeriodStamp_SelectedIndexChanged' and no extension method
>   'ddlPeriodStamp_Selectedindexedchanged "

This is the ASPX page that has the dropdown with the ddlperiodstamp.

```
<asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="center">
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="label" SkinID="groupCaptionSkin" ForeColor="Navy" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="Small" Text="TreatmentGroup" />   
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlItemGroup" OnSelectedIndexChanged= "ddlPeriodStamp_SelectedIndexChanged" runat ="server" AutoPostBack = "True">
<asp:ListItem Value="" Enabled="false"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="ALL">ALL</asp:ListItem>
```

This is my code behind.

```
  protected void ddlPeriodStamp_selectedIndexchanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    DropDownList ddlItemGroup = (DropDownList)sender;

    if (ddlItemGroup.SelectedValue != null)
        try
    {
        ApplyGridFilter();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ;
    }
    finally
    {
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check in the entire project where you have referenced a call to `ddlPeriodStamp_SelectedIndexChanged`

Comment: I think you need to select your OnselectedIndexchanged method again or create new one, may be you changed id of dropdownlist but your designer class not updated(as dropdown id is different thann in method name).

Comment: method names are case-sensitive in C#

Comment: thank you very much , the error is now gone